# Insert index/Keys into an array

Tags: php, arrays

D

Could you give a an advice how to insert keys/index to a an array in a specific order
as you can se.... I would like to in the result index the values id1 = 3 id2 = 4 id3 = 5.
How do I do that?
This code

```
public static function getTest($ids){
    $input = array();
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $input['result'] = $ids;
    }

    $result = array('status'=>"success",
                    'message'=>"blah blah",
                    'result'=> $ids
              );
    var_dump($result);
    return $result;
}
```

produces this (getTest is called from another file and it gives out array(3,4,5))

```
array(3) { 
    ["status"]=> string(7) "success" 
    ["message"]=> string(9) "blah blah" 
    ["result"]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> int(3) 
        [1]=> int(4) 
        [2]=> int(5) 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is $input['result'] for?

Comment: that was me trying to make it work...it gives out the mentioned output without  all of this    $input =array(
        );
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $input['result']=$ids;
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an array the elements are in the order you added them:

```
$a = array();
$a[2] = 2;
$a[1] = 1;
$a[9] = 9;
var_dump($a);
// array(3) { [2]=> int(2) [1]=> int(1) [9]=> int(9) }
```

I am not really sure what you want but have a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) the page always helps my lot.

**Response to comment**:
Try this

```
foreach ($ids as $key => $id) {
    $input['result']['ID'.$key] =  $id;
}
```

Comment: I have this getTest::(array(3,4,5)); in the controller file, and it gives out the array to the get test function in an Api class. I want to getTest to give me an array in a orderly fashion back to the controller. Like this array(3) { 
["status"]=> string(7) "success" 
["message"]=> string(9) "blah blah" 
["result"]=> array(3) { 
[ID1]=> int(3) [ID2]=> int(4) [ID3]=> int(5) }
 }